# How to show a small table by inputting a value in another cell

Tags: range, show

I have a vlookup that will return a value.  I wish to show a small table based on that value in another location.  How do I accomplish this.  Sample attached

I have attempted to use =arrayformula but since it brings in overlapping I can not get it to work. I did not know what else to use.